# How to show GKPath in GameplayKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

is there a trick to show a GKPath?

for example my path:

```
class ScenarioPath: GKPath {

    //SET
    //   |  |  |  |  |  |
    // --A--B--C--D--E--F--
    //   |  |  |  |  |  |
    //6 punti con raggio quasi 600 e lato 500 va bene per scenario 2K * 3K
    static let lato = Float(500.0)
    static let maxY = Float(0.0)
    static let radius : Float = 600.0

    static let maxYNormalize = maxY - radius

    static let pts = [
        vector_float2(-lato,maxYNormalize),
        vector_float2(+lato,maxYNormalize),
        vector_float2(-2*lato,maxYNormalize),
        vector_float2(+2*lato,maxYNormalize),
        vector_float2(-3*lato,maxYNormalize),
        vector_float2(+3*lato,maxYNormalize)]


    init () {
        super.init(points: UnsafeMutablePointer(ScenarioPath.pts), count: ScenarioPath.pts.count, radius: ScenarioPath.radius, cyclical: true)
    }


}
```

I'm looking for a simple func to show this path.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GameplayKit is not a graphics framework. It's a low-level toolkit you can use with *any* graphics framework. It doesn't have any features for drawing `GKPath`s because there are at least as many ways of interpreting a path as there are graphics toolkits and coordinate systems to do it with.

Since you're working with SpriteKit, it's not too hard to make a `CGPath` using the same set of points as your `GKPath`, then assign that to an [`SKShapeNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKShapeNode) to place in your scene.

You can find Apple sample code that does just that inside two of their larger demo projects: [AgentsCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AgentsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) and [DemoBots](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html).

Here's a bit to get you started:

```
// BTW, vector_float2 just a typealias for float2,
// and is ArrayLiteralConvertible, so you can write your array shorter:
let pts: [float2] = [
    [-lato,maxYNormalize],
    [+lato,maxYNormalize],
    // ...
]

// CGPoint extension to make the conversion more readable and reusable
extension CGPoint {
    init(_ vector: float2) {
        self.init(x: CGFloat(vector.x), y: CGFloat(vector.y))
    }
}

// make array of CGPoints from array of float2
let cgPoints = pts.map(CGPoint.init)
// use that array to create a shape node
let node = SKShapeNode(points: UnsafeMutablePointer(cgPoints), count: cgPoints.count)
```

This, of course, assumes that your path is specified in the same coordinate system as your scene. If not you'll need some transformations.